# Create new table that counts number of active rows

Tags: sql

So, I have a table that is more or less like this:

```
|  ID  |    Start    |    End    |
|  01  | 2018-01-01  | 2018-04-01|
|  02  | 2018-01-03  | 2018-02-02|
|  03  | 2018-02-01  | 2018-05-03|
```

(Table_1)

So, I'd like to have a new table that has one line for each day, and that counts the number of rows that are 'active' on that day (that is, where start<= day <= end).
Something like:

```
|      Day     |    Number of items    |
|  2018-01-01  |        1              |
|  2018-01-02  |        1              |
```

(going until current date)

I've tried:

```
SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN Start <= day AND (End IS NULL OR End >= day) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
FROM
(select date(d) as day
from generate_series(
  '2018-01-01', 
  current_date, 
  '1 day'
) d ) AS g, Table_1 AS ppr

GROUP BY day;
```

But it doesn't seem to work (no error, the query just takes forever and times out). The part where we create a new line for each day seems to work, I've tried it out on its own. The problem is counting the number of 'active' items on each day. Anyone sees the solution for this?

Comment: Are you using Postgres?

Answer (score 2):

The main problem I see with your current approach is that you are doing a cross join between the calendar table and the table containing the ranges.  What I think you intend to do here is an implicit join between your calendar table and table containing the ranges:

```
WITH calendar AS (
    SELECT date::date
    FROM generate_series ('2018-01-01'::date, current_date, '1 day'::interval) date
)

SELECT c.date, COUNT(t.Start) AS num_items
FROM calendar c
LEFT JOIN Table_1 t
    ON c.date >= t.Start AND (c.date <= t.End OR t.End IS NULL)
GROUP BY
    c.date
ORDER BY
    c.date;
```

### Demo

For explanation, we count the `Start` column in your data table.  This works because for a date which did not match to anything, there would just be a single record for that date, and the joined columns which all be `NULL` (and hence have a count of zero).  You may see in the demo that the edge case of a range with a `NULL` end is being handled correctly.